# UIStackview with UIKeyboard in swift2.0

Tags: iphone, swift2, ios9, uikeyboard, uistackview

I am using iOS9 with swift2.0.I my view controller handling two textfields and some labels.This two textfields contains in stackview and also labels contains in another stackview.I already setup universal app both portrait and landscape options,its working fine.But when i click on textfields then keyboard is up at that time keyboard is covering textfields so i can’t see textfield data.How to solve this issue and how to manage all constraints when keyboard is up and down?

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object:nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){

    print("keyboardWillShow")
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame:CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    print(keyboardFrame)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in

    })
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){

      print("keyboardWillHide")

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification){

    var info = sender.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()


    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.view.center.y = self.view.center.y - keyboardFrame.size.height
    })


}
func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification){

    var info = sender.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.center.y = self.view.center.y + keyboardFrame.size.height
    })

}
```

Comment: Its moving view up when clicking both textfields.Its not working properly.

Comment: what you want? @jasper it moves your view to upper keyboard,if you want just textfield move not whole view you can set your textfield center instead of view like that textfield.center.y and also detect your textfield by tag.